# Will the Ring clojure library work with clojurescript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

So I haven't been able to look this up anywhere? Since Ring is a clojure library would it work with clojurescript and if not then what's an alternative OAuth2 implementation that could be used with clojurescript.

Answer (score 1):

No. At least, not entirely.

Portions of Ring depend on Java. Ring uses Java servlets and Jetty webserver as the http backend, and that would have to be replaced if you were hoping to run on Node JS. If you were hoping to use Clojurescript, you could probably only use `ring-core` and `ring-devel`.

[Friend](https://github.com/cemerick/friend) or [Buddy-Auth](https://github.com/funcool/buddy-auth) would be good places to look if you want authentication in your Ring application

Answer (score 1):

I have very little experience with Ring, but I have used the [Macchiato](https://macchiato-framework.github.io/) framework on a number of projects. AFAIK its handling is modeled on Ring and it does include an [auth](https://github.com/macchiato-framework/macchiato-auth) mechanism… maybe worth checking out.